# month over month score evaluation

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I rate/score an item once monthly (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.), accepted values are 1, 3, or 5)... 
Utilizing the Month identifier formula (=IF(MONTH(TODAY())=1)... I'd like to display if the current month value is +,-,or = to the preceding months value.

Example: 
Jan =3, Feb =1 ----- Eval shows - (or decrease)
Feb =1, Mar =1 ----- Eval shows = (or neutral)
Mar =1, Apr =3 ----- Eval shows + (or increase)

[image: data grid]

Comment: Show your data structure and where you want the results. What is in row 4? Dates? Numbers? Text? We need that to write a formula that identifies the current month.  Edit your post to do that, then post a comment to notify followers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(INDEX(A2:L2,MONTH(today))>INDEX(A2:L2,MONTH(today)-1),"+",IF(INDEX(A2:L2,MONTH(today))<INDEX(A2:L2,MONTH(today)-1),"-","="))
```

I put a date into a cell and gave that cell the range name `today`. You can replace that with the function `Today()`